# Consumir imagenes que cargo desde asp,net con React.js

Tags: c#, sql-server, reactjs, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

vengo a pedir consejo. Estoy trabajando app asp.net con React js. al guardar las imagenes dentro de mi proyecto, uso el metodo ContentRootPath() para obtener mi ruta raiz y crear una carpeta dentro de ella. Ahora la carpeta donde se guarda los archivos estáticos no esta en la carpeta wwwRoot, sino en la carpeta public dentro de los archivos de React. Se que al momento de empaquetar la carpeta wwwRoot se crea, y los archivos dentro de la carpeta public terminan en ese lugar. El problema ahora es como hago para que mis archivos se guarden en ese lugar de manera dinamica y como haria para consumir estas imágenes porque debido al path me sale este error: **Not allowed to load local resource**.

Si no me explique bien, perdonen mi ignorancia. GRACIAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que lio... que tienen que ver los archivos estaticos de react, con los archivos que creas en el momento... y que tienen una ruta que deberia ser legible por react...me parece que de ahi viene tu confusion...

Comment: Hola gracias por comentar, exactamente ¿Cómo consigo una ruta que sea legible para react? en un principio pensé en ponerlo dentro de la carpeta public, aunque no se si es correcto o simplemente ¿lo dejo en una carpeta aparte?